# how do you reverse an element in a list in python

Tags: python-3.x, list, arraylist

Like if you have a list as names = ["Alice", "Opoku", "Kti", "Aben"] and you want to reverse a particular entry in the list like Alice as ecilA. How do you do that?

Comment: `names[0][::-1]`

Answer (score 1):

With a list containing strings, get the element of the list and slice it:

```
>>> list = ["Alice", "Opoku", "Kti", "Aben"] 
>>> list[0] = list[0][::-1]
>>> list
>>> ['ecilA', 'Opoku', 'Kti', 'Aben']
```